# Can't use cscope correctly under emacs evil-mode

Tags: emacs, cscope, evil-mode

I have the same issue with the guy, the link is below:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.vim-emulation/1404

when I try to use xgtags/xcscope with evil I have the following question:
xgtags/xcscope would open a new window with all search results and
this window/buffer is in normal mode, but enter wouldn't work to go in
to the source code file in the result list. I need to c-z to get to
emacs mode to jump to the source file.
Would it be possible to let evil go into emacs mode for result buffers
of cscope and gtags? or what is your approach regarding to this issue?

But I didn't find any solution on Internet. Is there anyone know how to solve the issue?

Thanks!
Jerry

Comment: I tried cscope and I don't have this problem: when in the *cscope* buffer, pressing «enter» takes me to the symbol definition. What is your version of emacs and evil ? I'm using the 1.0-dev installed with ELPA in Emacs24. (M-x evil-version)

Answer (score 0):

This is what works to enter `evil-emacs-state` when entering `dired-mode` (just replace with the mode used by xgtags):

```lisp
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (evil-emacs-state)))
```

put it in you .emacs or try temporarily with `M-x ielm`.

Comment: couldn't find the appropriate mode… yet.

Comment: try replacing dired-mode-hook with cscope-minor-mode-hooks (not convinced though)

Answer (score 0):

Ehvince, thanks very much.

But enter wouldn't work to go in to the source code file in the result list.

The following is my config:

4 ;;coscope

5 (require 'xcscope)

6 (setq cscope-do-not-update-database t)

92 ;;evil

93 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/evil")

94 (require 'evil) 95 (evil-mode 1)

96 (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (evil-emacs-state)))

Comment: First of all, too bad for you, because it's working fine with my xcscope. Then, as I said, you have to adapt my answer. I gave the example with dired-mode (because I didn't know cscope) but cscope uses another mode. You have to discover that ! Finally, you should not have written an answer, but a comment to my answer or editing your question would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the issue is solved.
Thanks, guys.
I forgot to set following:
 (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC") 'cscope-show-entry-other-window)